# changing path of program files doesnt work on windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, ssd, windows-registry, windows-8.1

I have an SSD drive with windows 8.1 and another regular SATA drive for none OS data.

I want to put the `Program Files` and `Program Files (x86)` folders on the SATA drive to preserve room and extend the life span of the SSD drive.

I've edited the Registry keys at

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion`

I moved all the program files folders to the other drive and rebooted the machine.

Unfortunately nothing seem to have changed, new program still go by default to the C:\Program Files which is on the SSD drive.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yeah: 1) You're trying to move Program Files (which is a really BAD idea at best), and 2) You're doing it wrong by just changing registry entries.  I'm not even sure why you think this would work?

Comment: A junction point would probably be a better way to do it, but keep in mind moving the `Program Files` / `Program Files (x86)` folder is not officially supported by Microsoft (i.e. things might not work properly): http://support.microsoft.com/kb/933700

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not moving program files.  Like the comments suggest that is a bad idea.  That said there is no rule that you need to install programs to program files.

The easy answer here is just change the default install path to your secondary SATA drive and go from there.  That's how I run my machine, I put the OS and some basic common use utilities/programs (browser, AV, etc) on the SSD and all programs (games...) go onto the SATA drive.

I guess I dont see the value added in moving program files.

Comment: what about using a symbolic link from the SSD program files directory to an alternate directory on the sata drive?

Comment: Could you add instructions for changing the default installation path?

Comment: Normally during the installation process one of the steps is to select a location.  If no chance presents itself you may need to select 'advanced setup' early on in the installer steps.  If you are not sure about the other settings that pop up just press next as they will normally default to the same thing as a simple/standard setup.